# check if number is precise float (int) or actual float value

Tags: javascript

I'm doing a math comparison to check if three numbers are the same or if two of them are the same. I thought i'd go about it by doing:

```
var num = 5 + 5 +5;
alert(num/3);
```

which results in `5.0` obviously, if one number is off it goes into a float.
However how do i go about comparing if the result is `5.0` or `5.5`?

I tried:

```
if (num%1 == 0) { ... }
```

Which gave me if the number is an int or not, but now i'm lost :P

Comment: What about if your three numbers are 6, 3 and 0? You'll get 3.0, which would incorrectly pass your test. If you describe your actual scenario in less-abstract terms, we might be able to offer you a better approach.

Comment: Crap :/ Didn't think of that.. Bha was hoping to skip the use of `switch` and make the length of the numbers static, tried to create a dynamic way to check how many numbers are the same :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use something like this:

```
if (parseInt(num) == num) { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider to use Math.round() function.

```
var num = 5 + 5 + 6;
if((num / 3) == Math.round(num / 3)) {
    document.writeln("The three numbers are the same");
} else {
    document.writeln("The three numbers are not the same");
}
```